# ASPX page not showing up in any browser

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am developing an aspx page, almost everything works fine if vb-design, but nothing showing up in IE, Firefox, Chrome...I can't open the page in any browser...so I can manage to see my project. But I can't run it, I don't know where to look or what to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 60%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 1006px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 194px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            width: 194px;
            height: 122px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            height: 122px;
            width: 600px;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            width: 600px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            
            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLastName" Text="Last name"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOfferDate" runat="server" Text="Offer date"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Calendar ID="calOfferDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" Width="200px">
                            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
                            <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
                            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
                        </asp:Calendar>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOfferExpirationDate" runat="server" Text="Offer expiration date"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Calendar ID="calOfferExpirationDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" Width="200px">
                            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
                            <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
                            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
                        </asp:Calendar>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
           <hr />
            <br />
            <span class="auto-style2"><strong>Set up your car
            <br />
            </strong>
            <table class="auto-style3">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEquipmentLevel" runat="server" Text="Equipment level"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cbEquipmentLevel" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Standard</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Evolved</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Advanced</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Premium</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWarrantyType" runat="server" Text="Warranty type"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblWarrantyList" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Standard (2 years)</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Extended (5 years)</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOptionals" runat="server" Text="Optionals"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblOptionals" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblOptionals" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="727px">
                            <asp:ListItem>Alloys wheels</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Climatronic</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Automatic pilot</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Road alert</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Navigation</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDiscounts" runat="server" Text="Discounts"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style7"><strong>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWholepayment" runat="server" Text="Whole payment"></asp:Label>
                        </strong>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWhole" runat="server" />
                        <strong>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCasco" runat="server" Text="CASCO Insurance"></asp:Label>
                        </strong>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCasco" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDiplayOffer" runat="server" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="White" Text="Display Offer" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </span>
        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="LblMessage" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: That is the main problem, I can't run it...it won't open in anything

Comment: Did you register the website on the IIS Manager?

Comment: No, but now I did, thank you. Problem solved for now :)